# No guarda los datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

La base de datos 5 tablas: cliente,habitacion, historial,personal y usuario.

En la tabla de usuario esta el ID el cual pasa tambien para el de la habitacion como id_usuario, hago mi formulario normal y sale que se ha creado la habitacion, pero no la muestra ni la guarda, desde la base de datos si puedo insertar datos.

No me lanza ningun error, solo no guarda en la base de datos, pienso que es por la relacion de ID con id_usuario pero no se que hacer.

Editado: Se supone que la ID de la tabla usuario que me da deberia asignarse a la de la habitación.

Tabla usuario:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `rango` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuario`
--

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `usuario`, `clave`, `rango`, `cedula`) VALUES
(1, 'eduardo', 'eduardo', '1', 262944),
(18, 'EduardoJ', '123456', '1', 262);
```

Tabla habitacion:

```
CREATE TABLE `habitacion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `n_habitacion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tipoh` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `habitacion`
--

INSERT INTO `habitacion` (`id`, `estado`, `n_habitacion`, `tipoh`, `id_usuario`) VALUES
(10, 'Ocupado', '1', 'Completa', 18);
```

Mi codigo es este.

HTML:

```
 <form action="validarhabitacion.php" method="POST">
                <table  style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><CENTER><h2>Crear Habitación<h2></CENTER></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><h3>Estado de Habitación<h3></td></font>
                        <td><input name="estado" type="text" placeholder="" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><h3>Número de Habitación<h3></td>
                        <td><input name="n_habitacion" type="text" placeholder="" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h3>Tipo de Habitación<h3></td></font>
                        <td><input name="tipoh" type="text" placeholder=""required></td>
                    </tr>


    <td colspan="2">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Crear"></center>

    </td>
    </table>
    </form>
```

PHP archivo validarhabitacion.php:

```
<?php



$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$n_habitacion=$_POST['n_habitacion'];
$tipoh= $_POST['tipoh'];





    require("connect_db.php");




                mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO habitacion VALUES('','$estado','$n_habitacion','$tipoh')");
                //echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
                echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Habitación Creada");</script> ';
           echo "<script>location.href='controlhabitacion.php'</script>";



?>
```

Conexion a base de datos:

```
<?php


        $mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "root","", "aeduardo");
        if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
            die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno()
                . ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        else
        ?>
```

Comment: muestrame como haces la conexion a la base de datos +

Comment: Listo, acabo de agregarlo al codigo

Comment: por que al inicio de tu insert, tienes unas comillas vacias? que indican? @EduardoOrtiz

Comment: por favor añade la estructura de tu tabla por que ahi donde te menciono debe estar el error

Comment: El de la comilla es es el campo ID, ya he editado y puse las dos tablas

Comment: creo que la estructura de tus tablas no es la adecuada, por que al menos la tabla habitación debería tener el id del usuario pero como foreing key no?

Answer (score 1):

primero empieza por hacer un sistema de validaciones en la cual puedas descartar los posibles errores que pueden surgir y asi depuras el codigo, te dejo una conexion estable que la puedes implentar en tu archivo `connect_db.php`
NOTA: el campo del id para mandarlo asi vacio debe `AUTO_INCREMENT`

y el resto en `validarhabitacion.php`

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('Falló mysqli_init');
    }

    //Process of connection to the database
    if (!$mysqli->real_connect("localhost", "root","", "aeduardo")) {
        die('Error de conexión (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //se valida que todos los datos lleguen y lleguen llenos
    if ( (isset($_POST['estado']) && !empty($_POST['estado']) ) &&
         (isset($_POST['n_habitacion']) && !empty($_POST['n_habitacion']) ) &&
         (isset($_POST['tipoh']) && !empty($_POST['tipoh']) )  ) {


//traer el id del usuario
         $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE usuario ='nombre_elegifo'";
         $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
         $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      if($fila>0){
        $id_usuario= $fila['id'];
      }




//se pasan valores a las variables
        $estado=$_POST['estado'];
        $n_habitacion=$_POST['n_habitacion'];
        $tipoh= $_POST['tipoh'];
        //se crea el query
        $sql="INSERT INTO habitacion VALUES ('".$estado."','".$n_habitacion."','".$tipoh."','".$id_usuario."')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        //si fue exitoso el devuelve un true
        if($result){
            echo "<script>alert('se inserto en la BD');</script>";
        }else{
            //reultado si no se hizo la insercion
            echo "<script>alert('problemas desde la BD');</script>";
        }
    }else{
        //descarte de los campos vacios
        echo "<script>alert('no llegaron los datos');</script>";
    }
```

NOTA2: `DEBES PASAR EL ID DE USUARIO YA QUE EN LA DB ES NOT NULL`

espero te sirva y la marques como valida Bro ReNiceCode

Comment: por que dejas las comillas simples solas al incio, con que valor se llenarían al momento de hacer un registro? por que así le esta haciendo falta ese valor

Comment: por eso pongo la nota que debe ser AUTO_INCREMENT para la que bd lo ponga automaticamente

Comment: bajo ese caso ni siquiera se deben poner las comillas por que entonces habrá un conflicto al guardar el valor del id, pues cuando el id es PK si siquiera se declara en la query

Comment: cierto... deberia de mandar directamente el NULL

Comment: no debería en el campo del PK mandar nada, si lo declaró como PK ese campo no debe estar presente, pues cualquier valor asignado tendrá conflicto

Comment: @srJJ Como pasaria el campo ID de usuario? creo que allí esta el error el cual no se guarda, ya quite las ''

Comment: SI... Debes ponerlo en in input tipo hidden, o en una variable de session, o en su defecto antes de insertar haces una consulta que te traiga el id del usuario que quieres y ese campo que llegue lo mandas en el insert, todo depende de la logica que tenga tu pg

Comment: asigna el id del usuario en cuestion a una variable y posteriormente mete esa variable a tu query y deja el espacio del id de habitación sin valor alguno ahi no pongas nada

Comment: @Alfredo maestro al no pasarle nada tendria que cambiar tambien el query, ya que como la consulta no va completa, tendria antes del value hacer referencia a todos los campos que si va a mandar... verdad ?

Comment: lo que trato de decir es esto, el id de la tabla habitación es PK por lo tanto el gestor lo mete de manera automática, segundo no debe colocar nada en el espacio del id mencionado, tercero el id que si debe declarar es el del usuario pues ese viene de otra fuente(tabla) entonces si lo asigna a una variable podrá meterlo en su consulta

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz, ahi te dejo algo de como puedes ponerle el id indicado, he implementando lo que recomento el Maestro Alfredo...